Which Object and Data Point can be used to identify a Guest Visitor in Enhanced Web MIAW?
With standard chat, LiveChatTranscript returned IP address. With enhanced chat, we are unable to locate any identifier for guest customer to understand repeat contacts. I have heard from support agents that there is no identifier for guest visitors, are there any alternatives we can use to track IP address, cookies or something?
